# Error al subir video a mi servidor

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola neesito poder subir videos a un servidor, utilice el mismo archivo que he usado en ocasiones anteriores para subir fotos, pero me da un error que realmente no se que pueda ser...Si alguien pudiera decirme que mas necesito cambiar para poder subir los videos lo apreciaria mucho.

Esta es mi funcion para tomar la info:

```
function guardarejercicio(){
        if ($('#nombre').val() == "") {
            SweetAlert("error", "Todos los campos son obligatorios");
        }else{
                var file = $('#uploadimage').get(0).files[0];
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('uploadedfile', file);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    url: '../api/uploader/video_uploader.php',
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(returnedImagen){
                        var skillboard = ((document.getElementById('skillboard').checked) ? 'Y' : 'N');
            $.post('../api/v1/exercise/create/', {
                nombre: $('#nombre').val(),
                skillboard: skillboard,
                tipo: $('#tipo').val(),
                video: returnedImage["data"],
            }, function(returnedData) {
                if (returnedData["error"] == false) {
                    SweetAlert("url_success", returnedData["msg"], "ejercicios.php");
                } else {
                    SweetAlert("error", returnedData["msg"]);
                }
            });
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Este es el video_uploader.php

```
    <?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
function renameDuplicates($path, $file){   
    $fileName = pathinfo($path . $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $fileExtension = "." . pathinfo($path . $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $returnValue = $fileName . $fileExtension;
    $copy = 1;
    while(file_exists($path . $returnValue)){
        $returnValue = $fileName . '-kl-'. $copy . $fileExtension;
        $copy++;
    }
    return $returnValue;
}

$uploaddir = "videos/";
if (!file_exists($uploaddir))
    mkdir($uploaddir, 0777, true);

$file1 = str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
$file1 = renameDuplicates($uploaddir, strtolower(basename($file1)));

$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file1;
if (is_writable($uploaddir)) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile)) {
        $url = "videos/" . $file1;
        $json = array("response" => "success", "data" => $url);
        echo json_encode($json);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("response" => "error", "data2" => $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"]));
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("response" => "error", "data2" => "TERRIBLE ERROR!"));
}
?>
```

Al intentar subir me sale esto :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al parecer el directorio `$uploaddir` no tiene permisos de escritura... o no exite.

Comment: Pueden ser diferentes cosas, pero cuando envias un archivo, al tu recibirlo con $_FILES['uploadedfile'], el indice que usas puede no existir, me refiero a que no todos los archivos subidos tendran un indice llamado "uploadedfile", mira esto: https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.files.php, mi sospecha es que estas apuntando a un indice que no existe en $_FILES y no al archivo, por lo tanto falla el resto de cosas. tambien si no estoy mal, he visto muchas vecez que cuando se envia audio o video proccessData de jQuery normalmente tiene como valor true, pero no se si tiene algo que ver